# How to set up Kubernetes Ingress that gzips

Tags: kubernetes, gzip, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following kubernetes ingress and I was wondering whether there is a way to tell it to gzip all responses. I am running this on google kubernetes engine. I tried adding the following annotations but no dice:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/server-snippets: "gzip on;\ngzip_comp_level 5;\ngzip_http_version 1.1;\ngzip_min_length 16;\ngzip_proxied any;\n;"
```

my kubernetes code is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: the_ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: some_static_up
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: some_cert
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: some-app-web-client
    servicePort: 60000
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: you deployed the nginx ingress controller yourself?

Comment: Hi @ArghyaSadhu , I deployed it via kubernetes by adding the annotations

Comment: @HeronAlgoSearch, but have you installed it on your **GKE** ? e.g. following [this guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) from official documentation ?